# Asp.net Adding header to all page methods

Tags: asp.net

I want to add a CSRF token HTTP header to all page method requests that happen from the client. Is is possible to append data like this across the board?

The methods are called like

```
PageMethods.Method()
```

in javascript

Comment: You can accomplish this with IIS or using HttpModules: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307996

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1  You can use

```
xhr.setRequestHeader //method based on XMLHttpRequest concept
```

you can read this link

http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/?blogid=118

2 You can use HttpHandler also in order to customize your header, but it's full .net technology, without javascript

Comment: that link is exactly what I need, but I am not using jQuery to make these calls unfortunately. Will HttpHandler be able to perform a similar function?

Comment: yes you can custommize your header, http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader-method